# How can I know wether a pushbutton is toggled or not?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, signals-slots, qpushbutton

Like seen on the picture, I have 96 pushbuttons initially green.
Once clicked on a button ( `toggled(bool`) ) it becomes red.

What I want to do is to disable all red buttons once I click on the OK button.

How can I do that ?

If the OK button closes this window, what should I do so that the modifications ( disabled buttons ) are saved once I open the window again!

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using `isCheckable` and `isChecked`?

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in qt togglebuttons are jut norlmal buttons, those inherit the qAbstractbutton

https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#checked-prop

there you can use the bool isChecked() method:

> This property holds whether the button is checked.
>
> Only checkable buttons can be checked. By default, the button is
>   unchecked.

so I imagine, you have the grid in some kind of array you can browser in a for loop...

so you can do:

```
for(...)
{
    ui->x->setEnabled(!ui->x->isChecked());    
}
```

Comment: The suggestion still applies, I'd consider to link Qt 5 docs though, nowadays.